# Joining (union) of Sets inside a Set in Java

Tags: iterator, set, java-7, java, set-union

I have a map where the values are sets of integers. What i'd want to do is to get in the best way possible (using only the Java API would be great) the union of all the sets of Integers.

```
Map<Long, Set<Integer>> map;
```

What I thought so far is to loop through the values() of the map and manually add to the big Set:

```
Set<Integer> bigSet = new HashSet<>();
Iterator<Set<Integer>> iter = map.values().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
    bigSet.addAll(iter.next());
```

Also a collection for the union backed by the map would be great.
Unfortunately i am stuck with Java 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the one hand you could use the new Java 8 fluent interface

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

Set<Integer> myUnion = map
        .values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(set -> set.stream())
        .collect(toSet());
```

On the other hand I would suggest taking a look at [Guava's SetMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) if you can use external libraries.

Comment: And why is that better than what OP is already using? Can you add more info?

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with java 7 ... Still, isn't there any java 7 api-way to do that? A backed collection for the union would be great. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Pshemo I wouldn't say it's better without any context but depending on the size of the map it could be a performance win (if you use parallel stream).